# Ext js override init component function

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, overriding

I am trying to override some code in the `initComponent` function of the `Ext.window.MessageBox` class. But none of the things that I change get applied.

What is the problem here? Am I missing something?

```
Ext.define('hds.override.MessageBox', {
    override: 'Ext.window.MessageBox',

   initComponent: function() {

    console.log("init component 1"); //not reached

    this.callParent();


    console.log("init component 2"); //not reached
  }


});
```

Edit:

I have also tried replacing override with extend and the inside intiComponent is still not reached. Do I need to change the location of the file when changing to extend??

Comment: do you call `this.callParent()` in your function? and are you sure that you need to override `Ext.MessageBox` and not `Ext.window.MessageBox`?

Comment: I have tried with callParent but it did not help

Comment: and did you try to override `Ext.window.MessageBox`?

Comment: Yes, Nothing changed. But I have updated my code because I think that was another mistake

Comment: ok I tested a few things and cause Ext.MessageBox is a singleton it gets instantiated before your code is reached so you need to extend it

Comment: I have also tried that. Replacing override with extend. But the code in the initComponent is still not reached. Do I need to put the extend file to a different location than the overrride file?

Comment: it seems impossible to override a singleton, you could try to google for workarounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want is to change the behavior of `Ext.Msg` which is an instance of the class `Ext.window.MessageBox` you need to make it an instance of your overridden class:

```
Ext.define('MyMessageBox', {
    override: 'Ext.window.MessageBox',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();
        //your changes here..
    }
},function() {
    Ext.MessageBox = Ext.Msg = new this();
});
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amitaviv99/yvdwG/41/) where I changed the default padding inside initComponent